# Re-mapping array list values - from subtype to super (sonar qube)

Tags: java

Bar extends Foo, and I need to return List of Foos based on List of Bars

Below code works:

```
private static List<Foo> getList(List<Bar> list) {
       return list.stream()
               .map((Bar e) -> (Foo) e)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

But I get sonar error:

> contrib:FII_USE_FUNCTION_IDENTITY This method declares a no-op
>   (identity) lambda method rather than just specifying
>   Function.identity()

I don't uderstand the sonar message as it is not actually no-op.

- is there a way to implement this sonar compliant and in more elegant manner?

Comment: Side note: since `map` takes `Function<? super T, ...`, you can rewrite your lambda as `(Foo e) -> e` (I find that shorter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the simplest way is to do it via

```
private static List<Foo> getList(List<Bar> list) {
       return new ArrayList<>(list);
   }
```

which makes the whole function an overkill.

(I just use it as`List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>(list);`) when needed.

Sonar has no objection on this approach. (It would be interesting to see performance of these approaches though).

@user3487063 answer was very helpful though, revealing implicit upcasting mechanism

Answer (score 2):

Just avoid the explicit type casting and use [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) method on `Class`

```
return list.stream()
           .map((Bar e) -> Foo.class.cast(e))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Probably you can avoid exception by using `instanceof`

```
list.stream()
        .filter(bar-> bar instanceof Foo)
        .map(Foo.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, Intellij suggest further simplification on this by using
`.filter(Objects::nonNull)` (says the above is the same). See my comment above on user3487063, seems I could just do `return new ArrayList<>(list)` but I need to pass all these approaches through Sonar yet

Comment: sorry i did not get your question @NenadP

Answer (score 1):

It is asking you to do something like this ?

```
list.stream().map(Function.identity()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Function.identity code:

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
```

> Casting from a subclass to a superclass is called upcasting.
>   Typically, the upcasting is implicitly performed by the compiler.
>   Upcasting is closely related to inheritance – another core concept in
>   Java. It's common to use reference variables to refer to a more
>   specific type

Read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting)

Comment: He wants to *cast* Bar to Foo. How does a method that takes a T and returns a T help here?

Comment: Casting from a subclass to a superclass is called upcasting. Typically, the upcasting is implicitly performed by the compiler. Upcasting is closely related to inheritance – another core concept in Java. It's common to use reference variables to refer to a more specific type.

Comment: @GhostCat says Reinstate Monica, upcasting is implicitly performed by the compiler.

Comment: Hey @user3487063 this sound ok, I did not run it on Sonar yet but it achieves the same goal. The only thing is that Intelij says it is redundant, so collapsing it and following further Intelij recommendation I ended up with `return new ArrayList<>(list)` which makes whole function un-necessary :)